# NLog Layout with ${onexception} not displaying literal text

Tags: nlog

I have a Mail target to send an email for certain log entries.  I would like the subject line to be prepended with "EXCEPTION THROWN:" (including the colon) if the log event includes an exception.

My subject line layout is:

```
${onexception:inner=EXCEPTION THROWN:}AppName Log Event
```

But the email sent has a subject line of:

> AppName Log Event

None of the literal text within the ${onexception} layout renderer is included.  And yes, I am sure an exception was passed.  See below.

I thought maybe wrapping it in a literal renderer would help:

```
${onexception:inner=${literal:text=EXCEPTION THROWN:}}AppName Log Event
```

This gives me:

> EXCEPTION THROWNAppName Log Event

That's better, but still missing the colon.  It demonstrates that the issue isn't with a missing exception - the condition is being met because it's including at least some of the string.  It's still stripping the colon, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, nevermind.  Posting here in case anyone else does what I did.

I needed to escape the ":".  Once that was done, everything started showing up, even without using the ${literal} renderer:

```
${onexception:inner=EXCEPTION THROWN\:}AppName Log Event
```